# How do I get the number of characters of a varchar

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm try to do a trigger that limit the number of the characters when is inserting or updating

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trigpersonfone
 BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF phone ON PhonePerson
 FOR EACH ROW
   BEGIN
      IF :NEW.phone.LENGTH < 8 THEN 
         DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('The phone cannot have less then 8 numbers');
      END IF;
  END;
/
```

I'm using the oracle live and this ide don't show a good error log. Can someone tell me whats is wrong in my sql code? Thanks

Comment: Does it need to be a trigger?  This could be more easily done through a check constraint.

Comment: Yes Jon, it has to be a trigger. For a college work

Comment: use `select * from  user_errors` to display your errors

Comment: You tagged Oracle SQL Developer but you aren't using it for your Oracle course?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
:NEW.phone.LENGTH
```

doesn't work. This is no object having a `LENGTH` member. Use the [`LENGTH()`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions076.htm) function.

```
LENGTH(:NEW.phone)
```

Also `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUTLINE()` won't abort the DML. Phone numbers with less than 8 characters still can be happily inserted. Maybe you want to use [`RAISE`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/raise_statement.htm) instead.

Answer (score 5):

Use a `check` constraint, not a trigger:

```
alter table PhonePerson add constraint chk_phoneperson_phone check (length(phone) >= 8);
```

Comment: Then please complain to the person who wrote the assignment ;-)